# TYPO3 not sending email notifications

Tags: typo3

I've configured my TYPO3 instance such that it sends me an email every time someone logs in with my account (under User Settings -> "Notify me by email when someone logs into my account"), however, I'm not receiving any emails (not even in the junk folder). I logged in and out multiple times with no success. How do I go on about troubleshooting this?

Comment: But your instance can send mails? The test in Admin-Tool is successful (`Admin-Tools > Environment > Test Mail Setup`)? Have you set `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['MAIL']['defaultMailFromAddress']` and is the address allowed to send mails? (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/Configuration)/Typo3ConfVars/MAIL.html#defaultmailfromaddress

Comment: @JulianHofmannthe defaultMailFromAddress is already set, but the transport_smtp_* options seem to be incorrect (I'm looking under System -> Configuration). Where can I edit these values?

Comment: Another pitfall could be the SPF Record. Is your web server allowed to send mails in the name of your domain?

Comment: @PeterKraume I found the error. Typo-3 isn't sending emails to my  (admin) account's email address specifically, but will send emails to any other address. What could be the problem? There are no spam filters or such enabled.

Comment: Have you tested with different (external) mail addresses? Maybe your webserver tries to use local delivery with the same domain as the website, but the corresponding mail server is not the web server itself?